# How to use if else in php MVC

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i create a if else statement in MVC format php where

I am trying to put this code in my controller

if (all values of column A in table 1 of database B are present in colum A in table 2 of database B)

```
[Load Model A]

Else
[Load Model B]
```

Please help i dont know whether to write this in controller or in models

```
    public function ownercount(){
    $this->db->selectCount('id');
    $this->db->from('owner_register');
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
}

public function gymcount(){

    $this->db->selectCount('id');
    $this->db->from('gym');
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
```

In my controller i put this

```
            public function gym()
    {
        is_protected();

    $this->load->model->('adminmodel')
    $ownercount = $this->load->adminmodel->ownercount();

        $this->load->model->('adminmodel')
    $gymcount = $this->load->adminmodel->gymcount();

        if ($ownercount = $gymcount) {

            $data['message']=$this->Adminmodel->gymlist();
        $this->load->view('Admin/customer.php',$data);

            } else {
           $data['message']=$this->Adminmodel->gymlist1();
        $this->load->view('Admin/customer.php',$data);

           }  


}
```

This is what i write on my controller but 500http error shows up

Comment: A) Why would you want to do this? B) What actual code have you written? We could use a place to start.

Comment: I have edited questions

Comment: A 500 error should be accompanied by an error *message* (and line number), possibly in the logs if not in the browser. Find it and add it to your question. `$this->db->select Count('id');` looks questionable, though - that space looks like a syntax error.

Comment: Please help i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with one SQL's query ? :

`
select count(*) from table1;
select count(*) from table1 where colomnA in ( select colomnA from table2);

`

Comment: Do i put this command in controller or model and the columns are in different tables